# multiple instances of conky running, but no startup entry

Tags: kubuntu, autostart, conky

On Kubuntu 19.10 I installed conky from the repo, configured it, and made an autostart entry.
After a reboot, I see in System Monitor that two instances of conky are running, can't figure out why.

```
ps -auxf | grep conky
shmuel    1436  0.0  0.1  27660 12248 ?        S    13:08   0:00  \_ /usr/bin/conky
shmuel    2060  0.0  0.0   8896   924 pts/1    S+   13:13   0:00          \_ grep --color=auto conky
shmuel    1580  0.0  0.1  27656 12384 ?        S    13:08   0:00 /usr/bin/conky
```

If I kill the two conky processes that show in System Monitor, and then start conky from terminal, I get:

```
ps -auxf | grep conky
shmuel    4442  0.1  0.1  27664 12452 pts/1    S+   16:17   0:00  |       \_ conky
shmuel    4459  0.0  0.0   8896   848 pts/2    S+   16:17   0:00          \_ grep --color=auto conky
```

Comment: Hi, have you sorted out your issue of multiple conkys?

Comment: So I reinstalled conky, and now I am down to two instances of conky running at the same time (that's what I see in system monitor, anyways). Output of ps -auxf | grep conky is in my edited post

Comment: You can ignore the second one, the one with `grep --color=auto conky`. That's just a function of using `grep`. I would also ask that you check what you see in *System Settings > Startup & Shutdown > Desktop Session* in the last panel "On Login". If you have "Restore previous session" active, that may explain why you see additional conky entries the next time you login. I prefer to have "Start with an empty session" checked.

Comment: DK Bose that was it! Now I set the desktop to start with empty session, and that fixed it. This also explains other processes that started as if they had a life of their own. Post it as answer so I can vote it up!

Comment: Done! If you need a clarification about the footnote related to autostart, please feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When users start a new session, they can decide which applications should load automatically. The graphical interface for that is accessed via *System settings > Startup & shutdown > Desktop session*. The lowermost section titled "On login" allows the user various options:

**Image showing part of the Desktop Sessions interface**

[image: On login options]

For whatever reason, the default option is the first one, *Restore previous session*. Retaining this option, in some cases, could have unintended consequences.

Consider having an application in one's *autostart*. If this application is

- not specifically closed by the user (before logging out, shutting down or rebooting) or
- entered in the *Applications to be excluded from sessions* box,

the user could see additional instances of the application open or running after each login.

The combination I prefer is to have whatever I want in *Autostart*¹ together with *Start with an empty session*.

¹ In my autostart, I use a time delay to avoid potential "race" conditions. When a session starts, it's quite a busy time for the system. So I use a delay of 1 min for my conky and 2 min for Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

Check the contents of

> /home/`your username`/.config/autostart

and

> /home/`your username`/.config/autostart-scripts

remove any conky related files from there.

> ps -auxf | grep conky

that may show you what and where the conkyrc is starting from.

`/proc/<conky pid>/`

look through the files there to get more information about the running process

Comment: All I found in .config was the single autostart that I already knew about. I now uninstalled conky through "software center" and then when I ran "sudo apt remove conky*" there were still a lot of conky packages there (besides depenencies). So maybe I somehow installed multiple conkies?

Comment: What information did ps -auxf | grep conky give you?

Comment: Try removing the conky scripts that are starting up(if any). Kill the processes with `kill -s 9 <pid#> ` then check if they startup again after logout.

Comment: I removed (but did not purge) all conky packages, and  I get "ps -auxf | grep conky 
shmuel   10839  0.0  0.0   8896   924 pts/1    S+   19:53   0:00          \_ grep --color=auto conky"

Comment: It appears that you no longer have any conky processes running.  That is just the `grep` process listed there. Is that after logout/login? And reboot? If so then it seems you may have solved your problem.